# Placing Content in "a href" using CSS and nth-of-type

Tags: css

I'm trying to place content into an empty "a" tag on my Drupal site. 
The code I'm using is:

```css
.letter-grid div:nth-of-type(1) a {
    content: 'All' !important;
}
```

The site has just divs and an "a href" tag linking to other sub pages. Not sure what other alternative there is for applying such code. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: The code shows up when I inspect the element just not applying onto the site.

Comment: So you have `<a href='...'></a>` and you want something like `<a href='...'>All</a>`, achieved with CSS alone?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot edit that link manually, which is why I'm trying this method

Comment: The link is presently empty though? There's nothing in it?

Comment: Correct, empty and displaying nothing on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS2.1, `content` only applies to `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements:

```css
.letter-grid div:nth-of-type(1) a:before {
  content: 'All' !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="letter-grid"><div><a href="#"></a></div></div>
```

In the future, CSS3 might allow to replace the contents of an element with `content`, but that's just an idea in a draft, and is not supported by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate thing to do is modify the actual markup. Without doing this, you may be making a non-accessible solution, which may alienate some users.

If you cannot modify your markup, or you are sure the impact to visually-impaired users will be non-existent or negligible, you can present content in either the `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements:

```css
.letter-grid div:nth-of-type(1) a::before {
    content: "All";
}
```

I stress, however, that it's better to *modify the actual markup*. Do not alienate your users.